# PHP login from ASP.NET existing cookie

Tags: php, asp.net

This might be way out of my league but I need to have a php page with login security that is obtained from the cookie that is created from ASP.NET login page. I can get the cookie `_ASPXAUTH` in the php but I'm not sure where to go from there.

PHP:

```
$authCookie = $_COOKIE['_ASPXAUTH'];
```

This is the encrypted cookie and I'm not sure how I would go about using the cookie to allow authentication?

If I have a php login form then I would need to encrypt and match the cookie, thus needing a new login page, If i just check if cookie exist then thats no form of security. Sorry for the noob question I'm mainly looking for a direction to go.

PHP and ASP.NET are both on the same site/domain.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know any existing solution dedicated for PHP, but there is existing solution written in node.js: https://github.com/LeanKit-Labs/aspxauth

This package allows you to encrypt login/password into cookie which can be after compared with existing cookie. I think that you can rewrite this code into PHP version, it's not much code.